# Java Grade Calculator program for class kepp geting the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException."

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first question I've posted. I've used this site to look at other questions to help with similar problems I've had. After some cursory looking I couldn't find quite the answer I was looking for so I decided to finally succumb and create an account.

I am fairly new to java, only a few weeks into my first class. Anyway, my project is to create a program which takes any amount of students  and their grades, and then assign them a letter grade. The catch is, however, that it is on a sort of curve and the other grades' letter are dependent on the the highest. Anything equal to or 10 points below the best grade is an a, anything 11-20 points below is a b, and so on. I am to use an array, but I get this error when ran "`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.`"

I will go ahead and post my code down below. Thanks for any advice you may be able to give.

```
package grade.calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author nichol57
 */
public class GradeCalculator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the number of students");
       int number = input.nextInt();
       double[]grades = new double [number];
       for (int J = number; J >=0; J--) {
          System.out.println("Enter the students' grades");
          grades[J] = input.nextDouble();

          }
          double best = grades[0];

         for (int J = 1; J < number; J++) {

          if (grades[J] >= best){
                best = grades[J];
          } 
         }
         for (int J = 0;J < number; J++){    
             if (grades[J] >= best - 10){

                System.out.println("Student " + J + " score is " + grades[J] + 
                        " and grade is " + "A");
             }
             else if (grades[J] >= best - 20){
                  System.out.println("Student " + J + " score is " + grades[J] + 
                        " and grade is " + "B");
             }  
             else if (grades[J] >= best - 30) {
                  System.out.println("Student " + J + " score is " + grades[J] + 
                        " and grade is " + "C");
             }
             else if (grades[J] >= best - 40) {
                  System.out.println("Student " + J + " score is " + grades[J] + 
                        " and grade is " + "D");
             }
             else {
                 System.out.println("Student " + J + " score is " + grades[J] + 
                        " and grade is " + "F");
             }
          }  // end for loop for output

       }// end main method

}
```

Comment: *I've used this site to look at other questions to help with similar problems I've had.  After some cursory looking I couldn't find quite the answer I was looking for ..."*  That's 'cos you were looking on the WRONG SITE.  But we've fixed that now!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access **`grades[number]`** in the first iteration of your outer for loop, but only **0 to `number` - 1** are legal

```
double[]grades = new double [number];
   for (int J = number; J >=0; J--) {
      System.out.println("Enter the students' grades");
      grades[J] = input.nextDouble(); // trying to access grades[number] in first iteration
```

that could be easily fixed by changing your for loop to

```
for (int J = number - 1; J >=0; J--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, when you declare an array of size n it goes from 0.. to n-1

In your case, you can only go to grades[j-1]

Answer (score 0):

1. `for (int J =0; J < number; J++)`
2. `for (int J = number-1; J >=0; J--)`

You can use either of one to solve this problem.